# How to setup a variable mongo client-uri in Spring Framework XML config

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to make some modifications to our Spring config file, for connecting to mongo.  Right now, we simply define the URL

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongo_connection" client-uri="mongodb://server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test" />
```

I'm now setting up authentication on the mongo server, which would change the connection string to `mongodb://username:password@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test`.  However, I can't hardcode these into the XML; they will come from a different API on startup.

I know how to setup the URL in a seperate Java file:

```
public class MongoConstructor {

    String username = secret_username;
    String password = secret_password;
    String db = "db_name"
    String rs = "test"

    //uri="mongodb://server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test"

    public String getMongoConstructor() {
        return "mongodb://" + username + ":" + password + "@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/" + db + "?replicaSet=" + rs;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway for me to create that value before the bean is registered, and pass that value into the config file?  If not, is there anyway for me to override the config in the xml file later on?

EDIT: Having done more research, I've discovered plaveholders for Spring, which seems to be what I'm looking for.  However, I'm still struggling.  So far, I've made the change in the XML file:

```
<beans>
<mongo:db-factory id="devMongoConnection"
                          client-uri="mongodb://{username}:{password}@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test" />
</beans>
```

Since I can't use a properties file to store the credential information, I've made a Java file to initialize the username and password:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SecretImpl {

    Secret secret = Internal_API_For_Secrets();

    public SecretImpl(String username, String password) {
    }

    @Bean(name="username")
    public String username() {
        return secret.getUsername();
    }

    @Bean(name="password")
    public String password() {
        return secret.getUsername();
    }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is getting these secrets into the xml file. All the documentation I've seen so far seems to assume that I would use either xml or Java, not a mix.  They also seem to assume that the password can be placed in a properties files as plain text.

Comment: what  Internal_API_For_Secrets() does?

Comment: Its an internal java package for retrieving username and password from a third party vault.

Comment: take a look at the answer, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to go would be using [SpEL expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) for accessing either system properties or system environment variables with your credentials configuration.

The approach is described in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based).

For example, you can define system properties like this when running your program:

```
-Dmongo_username=your_username -Dmongo_password=your_password
```

and then reference those properties in your XML configuration like this:

```xml
<mongo:db-factory id="mongo_connection" client-uri="mongodb://#{systemProperties['mongo_username']}:#{systemProperties['mongo_password']}@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test" />
```

Or preferably, you can define the same information using environment variables. For example, in Linux or Unix based systems:

```
export MONGO_USERNAME=your_username
export MONGO_PASSWORD=your_password
```

and use those variables like this:

```xml
<mongo:db-factory id="mongo_connection" client-uri="mongodb://#{systemEnvironment['MONGO_USERNAME']}:#{systemEnvironment['MONGO_PASSWORD']}@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test" />
```

I am not sure if it will work, because it highly depends on how you are obtaining the credentials, but you could define a bean corresponding to a slightly modified version of your `SecretImpl` class:

```java
public class SecretImpl {

    Secret secret = Internal_API_For_Secrets();

    public String getUsername() {
        return secret.getUsername();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return secret.getUsername();
    }
}
```

in your XML file and reference the corresponding properties in your Mongo configuration, using SpEL again:

```xml
<bean id="secretImpl" class="your.pkg.SecretImpl" />

<mongo:db-factory
  id="mongo_connection"
  client-uri="mongodb://#{secretImpl.username}:#{secretImpl.password}@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test" />
```

Finally, you could try providing a modified version of the `MongoDatabaseFactory` for taking into account the API for obtaining the credentials. It is unclear in your question the version of the Spring Data library for Mongo that you are using, but assuming the most recent, the `MongoDatabaseFactory` abstraction is implemented in [`SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/fbf4d1baa8473cf97ce892c14bad807d8f960657/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java). The proposed solution will then consist of defining a class that, for example, extends that class providing the necessary artifacts for dealing with your API for obtaining the required credentials, something like (please, excuse the simplicity of the code):

```java
public class MyCredentialVaultMongoClientDatabaseFactory
  extends SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory {

  // For instance, you can keep a reference to the class required
  // for obtaining your credentials for separation of concerns
  // or use this factory class itself for fetching the credentials
  // private SecretImpl secretImpl;

  public MyCredentialVaultMongoClientDatabaseFactory(String connectionStringPattern, SecretImpl secretImpl) {
    super(
      connectionStringPattern.format(
        secretImpl.getUsername(),
        secretImpl.getPassword()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Your XML configuration could look similar to this (based for instance on [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/f088c94548142fbb0d598a814b9bfc6c8f35a0dc/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/resources/infrastructure.xml)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="secretImpl" class="your.pkg.SecretImpl">
        <!-- properties for accessing your vault -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="your.pkg.MyCredentialVaultMongoClientDatabaseFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="connectionStringPattern" value="mongodb://%s:%s@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test"/>
        <constructor-arg name="secretImpl" ref="secretImpl"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
        <property name="writeConcern" value="majority" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: The second method with the modifications to SecretImpl works for my case, thank you very much.

Comment: You are very welcome @SVill. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not clear what `Secret secret = Internal_API_For_Secrets();` does.

But you could register your own properties on application startup in `ConfigurableEnvironment`

## First option

You can achieve it the following way:

Implement your own `EnvironmentPostProcessor`:

```
public class MongoPropertiesEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        // I don't know where you get these credentials here from, adapt this to your needs
        String user = "user"; 
        String password = "qwerty";

        String url = String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test",
                user, password);
        Map<String, Object> mongoProperties = Map.of("mongo-url", url);
        environment.getPropertySources()
                .addLast(new MapPropertySource("mongo-properties", mongoProperties));
    }
}
```

Register that post processor with `spring.factories` file. Create this file in `META-INF` directory. By maven conventions it should be `main/java/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

There you specify the class name with package

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.config.MongoPropertiesEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

So, during startup your property `mongo-url` will be registered in `Environment` and will be also accessible with the placeholder.

From Java code:

```
@Value("${mongo-url}")
private String mongoUrl;
```

In xml:

```
<mongo:db-factory id="devMongoConnection" client-uri="${mongo-url}"/>
```

---

## Second option

Another option if you want to inject some bean that makes a call to the external API:

Declare an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`:

```
@Service
class MongoPropertyInjector implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // I don't know where you get these credentials here, adapt this to your needs, you can autowire a bean that makes a call to external API and make a call here
        String user = "user";
        String password = "qwerty";

        String url = String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@server_1:27000,server_2:27000,server_3:27000/db_name?replicaSet=test",
                user, password);
        Map<String, Object> mongoProperties = Map.of(
                "mongo-url", url
        );
        configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources()
                .addLast(new MapPropertySource("mongo-properties", mongoProperties));
    }
}
```

After this you can use the placeholder `${mongo-url}` both in your Java configs and in XML configs, just like in the example above.